# How does "reorder" in R work?

Tags: r

How does the formula in the first parameter of boxplot in the following code make the correct correspondence between b and a after a has been reordered.

```
a <- as.factor(c("TX", "NY", "WA"))
levels(a)
b <- c(5, 3, 2)
boxplot(b ~ a)
# Order the levels of a according to their value in b
a_reordered <- reorder(a, b)
levels(a_reordered)
boxplot(b ~ a_reordered)
```

Why doesn't b need to be reordered as well?

edit: I replaced my example with the concrete example of @Marius

Comment: Could you kindly replace those two variables `quantity` and `state` with dummy data you think best replicates your data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `boxplot(quantity ~ bymedian)` call, the order of states on the x-axis is determined by the order of levels for the `bymedian` factor. Compare `levels(x$State)` to `levels(bymedian)`, and you'll see why the two variables behave differently when used in a plot. Note that the data itself in `bymedian` hasn't changed order.

A quick example:

```
a <- as.factor(c("TX", "NY", "WA"))
levels(a)
b <- c(5, 3, 2)
boxplot(b ~ a)
# Order the levels of a according to their value in b
a_reordered <- reorder(a, b)
levels(a_reordered)
boxplot(b ~ a_reordered)
```

And just to make it clear what it means to say that the actual *data* hasn't changed:

```
> a
[1] TX NY WA
Levels: NY TX WA
> a_reordered
[1] TX NY WA
# Don't be confused by this extra attr(, "scores") bit: the line
# above is the actual data stored in the vector
#attr(,"scores")
#NY TX WA 
# 3  5  2 
Levels: WA NY TX
> b
[1] 5 3 2
```

Comment: The question is why doesn't b need to be reordered? I know that a_reordered has a "scores" attribute. Does the formula or boxplot use that attribute somehow?

Comment: `b` doesn't need to be reordered because the data in `a_reordered` is still in the same order, so `"TX"` is still in the same position in `a_reordered` as `5` is in `b`. Therefore, 5 will still be used as the y-value wherever "TX" is on the x-axis.